# Starting off in game development

Tags: game-design

Recently I acquired a myriad of free time and have decided that I want to learn how to program. My question is what language should a newbie start off in? I understand that each language has its own pros and cons, but were could someone who is interested in making games start off?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where to start with game development?](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/9292/where-to-start-with-game-development)

Comment: There is a difference between wanting to learn to program and wanting to make games. If you are genuinely interested in coding then 'Python' is often cited as the best one to start off on. If you just want to make a game then 'Unity' is a good program to use. Good Luck!

Answer (score 2):

Many choose to start with a simpler managed language such as C# or Java. If you really seriously want to go into large-scale 3d games you will almost certainly need to learn C++, but this is a difficult language and has a high learning curve.

The good thing about C# and Java is that they share a mostly C style syntax, so you can become more familiar with the syntax in a more forgiving environment for things such as memory management. If you choose C#, I have found Microsoft's XNA an excellent learning tool for beginners.

Answer (score 0):

Each language has it's ups and downs, I'd probably suggest you grab something like Unity3D where you'll still have to program, but you're going to see something much faster, as it worries about all the tedious stuff like drawing polygons, input and asset management.

When picking a language in Unity, I'd go for Javascript, it's easy, seems to be the most prominent in the community, and there's lots of people who understand it.

My personal preference was Boo (a python derivative) next to no one used it so support was pretty much my own work.

Comment: Been using Boo for years!!

Comment: Write more articles about Unity then :)

Comment: "... and have decided that I want to learn how to program." He want to learn to program, not how to do scripting. He could fall back on your idea if programming gets too hard though (no offence against scripting! Personally I prefer Lua though ;-)

Comment: @salmonmoose Didn't use for graphics / game programming :(