# Starting off C++ games development?

Tags: c++, 3d, graphics

I've just finished my 2nd year of college, and now that I have time on my hands I want to start working on a 3D game, though my stumbling point is trying to find the resources to learn C++ games development.

I'd like to code an engine from scratch, but since my lack of experience I'd guess I'm best to utilize libraries, but, I'm not certain of which ones to use.

Any advice would be appreciated for libraries to use, what books to read or any tutorials that you found useful when starting out.

Thank you!

Comment: See also [What are good games to “earn your wings” with?](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/854/998), [Where to start with game development?](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/9292/998), [What are some great tips for a beginner?](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/15856/998)

Comment: "What should I learn next" is not on-topic for the site.  It'll just be a list of whatever people's favorite thing is and not a real answerable question.  See also http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 1):

For C++ game dev, I learnt C++ on [learncpp.com](http://learncpp.com) and [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/), and worked with [SDL](http://www.libsdl.org). This is a great platform-independent combination. Of course, use SDL with [OpenGL](http://www.libsdl.org/opengl/) for GPU graphics rendering.

SDL is like the glue code between C++, your computer and the GPU. So, you can write a lot by yourself. SDL comes with great libraries available on their website. For example: sound effects library, font library, etc...

Comment: Downvoter: comment?

Comment: I didn't do it, but suggesting `cplusplus.com` is probably worth a downvote. There are many errors on that site.